# List elements are not visible in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create this toolbar thing , but when I am creating a list and a sublist , the image in the list element is not visible.

```css
.toolbar{
    text-align: right;
}
.toolbar-menu{
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
.toolbar-menu li{
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.toolbar-img{
    max-width: 20px;
}
.toolbar-tool ul{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container toolbar py-1 mw-100 px-5 ">
            <ul class="toolbar-menu">
        
                <li><a href="#" id="color" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Font Color"><image class="toolbar-img" src="toolbar/color-filling.svg"></image></a>
                    <div class="toolbar-tool">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Above ALl</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" id="Size" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Font Size"><image class="toolbar-img" src="toolbar/font-size.svg"></image></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"  data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Lock Note"><image id="lock" class="toolbar-img" src="toolbar/lock-open.svg"></image></a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
```

Please help me with it or suggest any other better method for creating a toolbar kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if you want the sublist to show on hover or not. But below I've edited your code so the sublist shows on hover. You need to decide when to not display:none. Also you could achieve this in js but I think this is much easier using just css.

If the images won't show, I don't have your images so I used random images on the internet and if you had trouble showing these images. Double-check your paths and image location :) (Also another tip for that, if you open the source code of your website and click on the src url, if it's properly linked it'll open in your browser)

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .toolbar{
        text-align: right;
    }
    .toolbar-menu{
        display: inline-flex;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .toolbar-menu li{
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .toolbar-img{
        max-width: 20px;
    }
    .toolbar-tool ul{
        display:none;
    }

    /* New addition */
    .dropdown:hover .toolbar-tool ul{
        display:block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container toolbar py-1 mw-100 px-5 ">
            <ul class="toolbar-menu">
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" id="color" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Font Color"><image class="toolbar-img" src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_231353.png"></image></a>
                    <div class="toolbar-tool">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Above ALl</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" id="Size" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Font Size">
                <!--Using the img tag and leaving the alt attribute empty because the icon doesn't convey anything https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/ -->
                <img class="toolbar-img" alt="" src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_231353.png">
                </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"  data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Lock Note"><image id="lock" class="toolbar-img" src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_231353.png"></image></a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
</body>
```

Side note:
For best practice you probably want to use the `img` tag and add an `alt` attribute as follows:
`<img src="sushi.jpg" alt="Salmon sushi" width="500" height="600">`

Comment: Could you also tell the other approach too when you said ' I'm not entirely sure if you want the sublist to show on hover'

Comment: The hover way is in the code. You can run the code I shared directly and see the hover method. If you are talking about the other approach, the other one I can think of is when you click on it. I can share that too, it’d be some JavaScript